# What is the most straightforward solution to save integers right aligned into a text file?

Tags: export, list-manipulation, alignment

As an example I have a data list of dimension {10, 5}:

```
data=Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/AxGXqgAb"]

{{15,0,0,69,250},{15,0,0,88,121},{15,0,0,107,248},{15,0,0,125,119},
 {15,0,0,144,246},{15,0,0,163,117},{15,0,0,181,244},{15,0,0,200,115},
 {15,0,0,219,242},{15,0,0,237,113}}
```

I want to export the integers (0-255) right aligned into a text file with 10 rows and 5 columns (no curly braces) and each integer should occupy 3 spaces with a white space in between.

My code does not exactly what I want and looks relatively complicated.

```
formatted=Map[NumberForm[#,{3,0},NumberPadding->{" ","0"},NumberPoint->""]&,data,{2}]

Export[StringJoin[imageDir,"\\timeStampBytes4.txt"],formatted,"Table"];
```

The output file contains:

```
  15       0       0      69     250
  15       0       0      88     121
  15       0       0     107     248
  15       0       0     125     119
  15       0       0     144     246
  15       0       0     163     117
  15       0       0     181     244
  15       0       0     200     115
  15       0       0     219     242
  15       0       0     237     113
```

What is the most straightforward solution for my problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Export["file.txt", dat, "Table", Alignment -> Right]
```

[`"Table"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) lists this as an option.  If you want more or specific space use `"FieldSeparators"`:

```
Export["file.txt", dat, "Table", Alignment -> Right, "FieldSeparators" -> "    "]

FilePrint["file.txt"]
```

> ```
> 15    0    0     69    250
> 15    0    0     88    121
> 15    0    0    107    248
> 15    0    0    125    119
> 15    0    0    144    246
> 15    0    0    163    117
> 15    0    0    181    244
> 15    0    0    200    115
> 15    0    0    219    242
> 15    0    0    237    113
> ```

Comment: @mrz Glad I could help. :-)