# Write formatted data line by line in a loop into a text file

Tags: export, files-and-directories

The following question is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138559/what-is-the-most-straightforward-solution-to-save-integers-right-aligned-into-a).

I have as example this list:

```
{{15, 0, 0, 69, 250}, {15, 0, 0, 88, 121}, {15, 0, 0, 107, 248}, 
{15, 0, 0, 125, 119}, {15, 0, 0, 144, 246}, {15, 0, 0, 163, 117},
{15, 0, 0, 181, 244}, {15, 0, 0, 200, 115}, {15, 0, 0, 219, 242}, 
{15, 0, 0, 237, 113}};
```

**I would like to open a file for writing and then `write the data right aligned line by line in a loop` (not at once with `Export`) to the file. Finally the file should be closed.**

The content of the file should be:

```
15    0    0     69    250
15    0    0     88    121
15    0    0    107    248
15    0    0    125    119
15    0    0    144    246
15    0    0    163    117
15    0    0    181    244
15    0    0    200    115
15    0    0    219    242
15    0    0    237    113
```

I tried the following:

```
list = {{15, 0, 0, 69, 250}, {15, 0, 0, 88, 121}, {15, 0, 0, 107, 248}, 
        {15, 0, 0, 125, 119}, {15, 0, 0, 144, 246}, {15, 0, 0, 163, 117},
        {15, 0, 0, 181, 244}, {15, 0, 0, 200, 115}, {15, 0, 0, 219, 242}, 
        {15, 0, 0, 237, 113}};

n = Length[list];

file = OpenWrite["d:\\output.txt"];

Do[
  Write[file, list[[i]]];
  , {i, 1, n}
  ];

Close[file];
```

*The text content is not right aligned and containes curly braces and commas:*

```
{15, 0, 0, 69, 250}
{15, 0, 0, 88, 121}
{15, 0, 0, 107, 248}
{15, 0, 0, 125, 119}
{15, 0, 0, 144, 246}
{15, 0, 0, 163, 117}
{15, 0, 0, 181, 244}
{15, 0, 0, 200, 115}
{15, 0, 0, 219, 242}
{15, 0, 0, 237, 113}
```

Comment: If you're willing to preprocess with a combination of `StringPadLeft` and `StringJoin`  to construct each line you could do this relatively painlessly with `WriteString`.

Comment: @MB1965: Could you please show it a short answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting output of OpenAppend\[\] to match what Export\[data,file,".csv"\] would output?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/formatting-output-of-openappend-to-match-what-exportdata-file-csv-would-o)

Comment: You can write to a stream using Export.  Or you can ExportString, then WriteString the result to the stream.  The purpose of Export/ExportString here is to create the desired formatting.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think it depends on the formatting desired. Since the OP wants to do it line-by-line if  a tab would suffice `ExportString[ line, "TSV" ]` should work, but otherwise the justification needs to be done by hand I think.

Comment: @MB1965 Right. Retracting close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So depending on whether tab separation is sufficient or not there are two approaches.

First is the basic string-it-all-together approach:

```
With[{file = 
    OpenWrite@FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "output.txt"}},

  Do[

   WriteLine[
    file,
    StringPadLeft[ToString@#, 6] & /@ d // StringTrim@*StringJoin
    ],
   {d, data}
   ];

  Close@file
  ] // Import
```

Alternatively if you can deal with tabs as your separators, not enforcing some width-convention (I think this is probably the more common case):

```
With[{file = 
   OpenWrite@FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "output.txt"}},

 Do[
  WriteLine[file,
   ExportString[
    {d},
    "TSV"
    ]
   ],
  {d, data}
  ];

 Close@file
 ]
```

I would generally prefer the second, myself, as the more I can stick with what WRI provides the easier my life tends to be.

Comment: Great. Is it possible to align the numbers to right in each column?

Comment: Yeah, replace `StringPadRight` with `StringPadLeft` should do it. And then put `StringTrim@*` in front of `StringJoin`.

Comment: @mrz edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: The first code works great. The second is left aligned.

Comment: @mrz I didn't change the second at all. Not sure there's a way to do left-aligned with tabs without specifying that at the text-editor level or something.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
list = {{15, 0, 0, 69, 250}, {15, 0, 0, 88, 121}, {15, 0, 0, 107, 248},
        {15, 0, 0, 125, 119}, {15, 0, 0, 144, 246}, {15, 0, 0, 163, 117},
        {15, 0, 0, 181, 244}, {15, 0, 0, 200, 115}, {15, 0, 0, 219, 242},
        {15, 0, 0, 237, 113}};

n = Length[list];

file = OpenWrite@FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "output.txt"};

Do[

  outputline = StringJoin[
                ToString[
                 PaddedForm[#, 3, NumberPadding -> {" ", ""}]] & /@ list[[i]
                ]
               ];

  WriteLine[file, outputline];

  , {i, 1, n}

  ];

Close[file] // Import


  15   0   0  69 250
  15   0   0  88 121
  15   0   0 107 248
  15   0   0 125 119
  15   0   0 144 246
  15   0   0 163 117
  15   0   0 181 244
  15   0   0 200 115
  15   0   0 219 242
  15   0   0 237 113
```

Comment: There's also another form that routes through `ExportString` but I forgot to add it to my answer.